# How do you display a views.py's variable linked to annotated queryset in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do you display a views.py's variable linked to annotated queryset in a django template? I know the annotated queryset returns correct data when I printed it out, but somehow the template for loop is not retrieving the data on the html page. Can someone please advise me on how to fix this issue? Thanks.

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                              DetailView,CreateView,
                              UpdateView,DeleteView)
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Pastry
from myapp.forms import PastryForm
from django.db.models import F
```

This line `ps = Pastry.objects.values('pastry').annotate(total=Count('pastry'))` returns correct data:

```
{'pastry': 'Brownie', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Cake', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Cupcake', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Fruit Tart', 'total': 1}
{'pastry': 'Muffin', 'total': 2}


class PollsListView(ListView):
    model = Pastry

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pastry.objects.all()

class PollsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Pastry

class PollsCreateView(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pastry_list')
    form_class = PastryForm
    model = Pastry

class PollsUpdateView(UpdateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pastry_list')
    form_class = PastryForm
    model = Pastry

class PollsDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Pastry
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pastry_list')
```

pastry_list.html  (template)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">

<a href="{% url 'pastry_new' %}">New Poll</a>
<h1>Voting for the favorite pastry</h1>

Somehow this code here is not displaying any data.
{% for p in ps %}
 {% for k, v in p.items %}
   {{k}}{{v}}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for pastry in pastry_list %}
    <div class="pastry">
        <h3><a href="{% url 'pastry_detail' pk=pastry.pk %}">
  {{ pastry.pastry }}</a></h3>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

 </div>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the value of the variable in the template or you don't know how to send it to the template? in top of that, in which view do you have that queryset?

Comment: I have the queryset as a variable. ps = Pastry.objects.values('pastry').annotate(total=Count('pastry'))
I want to retrieve this in the pastry_list.html template.

Comment: do you use it in a specific view?

Comment: I didn't. Do I have to? What type of view do I put it in? How would I access the view from the template without using {% url 'template' %}?

Comment: Of course, the view that renders your template, send the variable via `get_context_data()` method

Comment: Can you provide me an example? I don't quite understand. Thank you for helping me. I'm very new to python and coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More info can be found in the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)
Basically, you can send more variables to template via `get_context_data()` method

Sample:

```
class PollsListView(ListView):
    model = Pastry

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pastry.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ps'] =  = Pastry.objects.values('pastry').annotate(total=Count('pastry'))
        return context
```

With `get_context-data()`, your variable `ps` is available in the template `pastry_list.html`

Comment: Thank you that is the answer that solved it. Thank you so much for your quick reply.